# MySQL query for one result

Tags: mysql, database-design

Pretty straightforward question: is it more efficient to query a database table and search potentially tens of thousands of entries for the one matching result, or create another new table for that 1 result?

`SELECT n FROM x WHERE b = 1` OR `SELECT * from y`?

Comment: Use the search capabilities of your RDBMS - that's what it's for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your field `b` indexed and its cardinality is high - then first query will be enough efficient.